# Order Groups in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

How can I set the ordering of my groups in Tabulator?  It is not clear to me what determines which group comes first.  I would like to be able to re-order the groups.

Comment: You should include some code to see the groups

Answer (score 0):

From Documentation http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/group

Based on the order of array

```
groupBy:["gender", "color"], //group by gender then favourite color
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the order of the underlying items is what orders the groups.  So whichever group the first item belongs to will be the first group, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The order the groups are displayed on the table is determined by the sort order of the rows they contain.

The [Row Management Pipeline Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/lifecycle#row) shows that rows are first sorted, then grouped. This means that after sorting the rows Tabulator will iterate over the data row by row, creating groups as needed, so the group containing the first sorted row will be first etc.

So to reorder your groups, set the [Initial Sort](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.4/sort#intial) for the table